# Reading records from the database using NpgSql and Postgres 9.4

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am usng Postgres 9.4 and NpgSql 2.2.5 for my .Net application.Postgres is new to me and whenevr I try to execute the postgres function in the database,it is throwing me an error

Here is my C# code

```
public List<District> DistrictReadAll()
      {
          try
          {
              List<District> districts = new List<District>();
              using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(this.RealEsateDB))
              {
                  conn.Open();
                  using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                  {
                      cmd.CommandText = "district_read_all";
                      cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;                      
                      NpgsqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                      while (rdr.Read())
                      {
                          District objDist = new District();
                          objDist.DistrictId = (int)rdr["districtid"];
                          objDist.Name = rdr["name"].ToString();
                          districts.Add(objDist);
                      }
                      return districts;
                  }
              }
          }
          catch ( Exception ex)
          {

              throw;
          }
      }
```

Postgres function

```
create or replace function district_read_all()
returns refcursor  
as
$$
declare
    ref1 refcursor ;
begin
    open ref1 for 
    select districtid,name from district order by name asc;
return  ref1;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

public.district table definition

```
CREATE TABLE district
(
  districtid serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  activeflag boolean DEFAULT true,
  CONSTRAINT pk_district_districtid PRIMARY KEY (districtid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE district
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And the C# error stacktrace

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException was caught
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=ERROR: 34000: cursor "<unnamed portal 1>" does not exist
  Source=Npgsql
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  BaseMessage=cursor "<unnamed portal 1>" does not exist
  Code=34000
  ColumnName=""
  ConstraintName=""
  DataTypeName=""
  Detail=""
  ErrorSql=SELECT * FROM district_read_all()
  File=src\backend\commands\portalcmds.c
  Hint=""
  Line=168
  Position=""
  Routine=PerformPortalFetch
  SchemaName=""
  Severity=ERROR
  TableName=""
  Where=""
  StackTrace:
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses>d__0.MoveNext()
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject(Boolean cleanup)
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRowDescription()
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.NextResultInternal()
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 dataEnumeration, CommandBehavior behavior, NpgsqlCommand command, NotificationThreadBlock threadBlock, Boolean preparedStatement, NpgsqlRowDescription rowDescription)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(CommandBehavior cb)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cb)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at CarRental.DataAccess.DistrictAccess.DistrictReadAll() in c:\DotNetApplications\CarRentalGit\RJ.CarRental\CarRental.DataAccess\DistrictAccess.cs:line 58
  InnerException:
```

This is a very simple thing ,if I use Sql Server

Can anyone let me know what am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap and execute the query within a `NpgsqlTransaction` for it to work - see the [Using refcursors](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/manual-2.2.html#getting-full-results-in-a-dataset-object-using-refcursors) section of the manual.

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(this.RealEsateDB))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (NpgsqlTransaction t = conn.BeginTransaction()) 
    {
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            ...
        }

        t.Commit();
    }
}
```